# Cannot Write On Micro SDCard On BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, filesystems, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to save some files on micro SDCard. To check the availability of SDCard, I am using the following method;

```
private boolean isSdCardReady() {
    Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();

    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (e.nextElement().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/")) {    
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Even if this method returns true, when I try to save files, it gives exception `net.rim.device.api.io.file.FileIOException: File system is not ready`.

What does this means? If SDCard is not available, then why its listed in `FileSystemRegistry.listRoots()`?

How can I make sure that SDCard is available for writing?

My development environment:

- BlackBerry JDE Eclipse Plugin 1.5.0
- BlackBerry OS 4.5
- BlackBerry Bold with a 3G card

Comment: Are you doing that in device restart?

Comment: Interesting. Some special SD card. Can you create files from camera pp or other apps on your device? Is this card originally from this device?

Comment: Could you try to save files to camera folder? Just for try

Comment: @EugenMartynov: I think, we should keep removing these comments so that this post will remain clean.

Comment: Read answer about closing streams. Does it help?

Comment: @EugenMartynov: Tried that also. But result is still same.

Comment: i think you are executing the code before your device really wake up. try to attach `SystemListener interface`. here how you can do this. [Write safe initialization code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Write-safe-initialization-code/ta-p/444795)

Comment: @BBdev: Actually, I am not accessing the SDCard at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I was looking for "sdcard" while `rootsEnum.nextElement().toString();` returns "SDCard". Yeah, its case sensitive. Now, instead of using hard-coded "SDCard", I've changed the above method to the following;

```
private static String getSdCardRootDir() {
    Enumeration rootsEnum = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();

    while (rootsEnum.hasMoreElements()) {

        String rootDir = rootsEnum.nextElement().toString();

        if (rootDir.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/")) {
            return "file:///" + rootDir;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Using this, I got the root directory in its system defined case.

Answer (score 3):

1. Usually I had this error when I tried to access SD card on device restart. You have to postpone all operations in app until startup finished:

   ```
   while (ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().inStartup()) {
       try {
           Thread.sleep(500);
       } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
       }
   }
   ```
2. I remember one more possible cause mentioned [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/IOException-File-system-not-ready/td-p/23487). You have to close all streams after using.

Comment: Thats really useful piece of code. But I am not accessing the SDCard at device startup.