# BlackBerry - Access the media storage when device connected to System

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

When i launch the application, my app will search the database file from the following path (store/home/user/sample.db). If my blackberry device connects to a computer, and at that time **if i launch my application, it's not able to find the path and read the database (not able to access the path).**

In this above situation, i want to check it if the media storage is accessible or not; if not i need to display the warning message. Is there is any blackberry API avialable to check this scenario?

**Note:** 
 I know that we can change the media storage option, in the device -> options -> device-> storage, but i don't want to change this setting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry cfg file not found when device connects to computer and Desktop Manager open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780182/blackberry-cfg-file-not-found-when-device-connects-to-computer-and-desktop-manag)

Comment: correct. Is that any api to find that. My application has to find out is it able to access the store/user path.

Comment: Yes, as Peter shows in his answer, or is shown in the other question I linked to.  Check for the `store` root.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to detect if the device is connected via the USB cable, then I think you can get the USB connection state using

```
USBPort.getConnectionState()
```

and you should check the state for

```
SystemListener2.USB_STATE_CABLE_DISCONNECTED
```

In your case, I think you need to check to see if the root 'store' is available, which you can do using code like the following:

```
boolean avail = false;
Enumeration drives = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
while(drives.hasMoreElements()) {
    String root = (String) drives.nextElement();
    System.out.print("Supported File System Root = " + root);
    if(root.equalsIgnoreCase("store/")) {
        avail = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify, when you connect your device to your computer, select the charge only option, otherwise the computer mounts the media storage, and is inaccessible to the device.